# Entity Framework 4 - is it good to add a custom field?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I create a desktop application using C# + EF 4.0. I'm aware that it's normal to add a custom **method** to Entity Framework EntityObject using partial classes:

```
public partial class EntityModel: EntityObject{
   public void MyMethod() { ... }
}
```

But I need to add a custom field to store an information that I don't want to hold in database.

So would it be normal or is there any way to do it?

Comment: It is acceptable, but you may want to look for opportunities to do that in a ViewModel.

Comment: Based on what you have said, it's correct.  But without knowing more about your code, it's hard to say conclusively.

Comment: Mike, it seems like you bother about my rate more than I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just add the property you need like:

```
public string MyCustomField { get; set; }
```

But bear in mind that it's stateful for that object so it's not going to persist **anywhere** unless you do that yourself and it's going to hold a different value for each object, unless of course you made it static, but I would ***strongly*** recommend against that.

Comment: Property is going to be compiled to a private field (and a method). So that's why I asked about a field.

Comment: @AlanDert, I'm confused at what the resulting IL has to do with the validity of extending an entity with an instance property.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it's related to the class and doesn't really belong somewhere else, then it's completely normal.